# How to use ZenMate VPN on linux with OpenVPN

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, openvpn, lubuntu

Following the guide for connecting to a ZenMate VPN server through OpenVPN on Ubuntu did not work on the Ubuntu variant Lubuntu; saying "connection lost" after attempting to connect. The solution -for anyone who followed the guide- is to change the setting next to the 'Password' field within the VPN connection editor to '... all users' instead of '... this user'. Save and retry the connection; it should now connect.

Answer (score 0):

The short solution -for anyone who followed the ZenMate Ubuntu guide on Lubuntu- is to change the setting next to the 'Password' field within the VPN connection editor to '... all users' instead of '... this user'. Save and retry the connection; it should now connect.

For users on linux distributions other than (L)Ubuntu, and/or those who didn't follow the guide on ZenMate's website, there are a few extra steps required before using their VPN. First make sure GNOME NetworkManager is installed with the OpenVPN add-on; installed with the terminal(Ctrl Alt T) command: sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome. Then follow these steps:

1. Login/create an account on ZenMate's website
2. Login, go to 'My Account' and click on 'Configure New Device' under 'OpenVPN'.
3. Select 'Open VPN' for Protocol, and a country server to connect to (America if free account), select 'ZenMate Premium Server...' in the next field if premium user (proxy if free).
4. Enter a name for the connection and optionally select Extra Features, then click 'Save'.
5. Click 'View Configuration' on the 'New Device' under OpenVPN in the My Devices menu.
6. Save the Username and Password (entered into corresponding OpenVPN input fields later)
7. Click 'Download Configuration', then save and extract(unzip) the .zip file to an empty folder; this contains the vpn configuration files used to connect to ZenMate servers.
8. Add a new VPN connection by Right clicking the network icon near the bottom right of the screen, then click edit connections, then the plus sign at the bottom left of the Network Connections window, select 'Import a saved vpn configuration...' from the drop down menu (labeled 'Ethernet') and click Create.
9. A selection Window should open; go to where the downloaded .zip was extracted and select 'openvpn.ovpn', click 'Open'.
10. Optionally rename the new VPN, and fill in the User name and Password fields with the generated ones from the ZenMate 'Server configuration' page. *click the icon at the end of the password field and change it to 'store for all users'.
11. Click Save to create the new VPN and click on it in the Network Manager.

It should now successfully connect to Zenmate through OpenVPN.

Comment: There's no "View Configuration" on the page (step 5)